# UPDATE column based on 2 other Columns Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My table has 5 columns. I would like to

```
UPDATE Column5='TEACHER' IF Column2='Y' 
AND 
UPDATE Column5='STUDENT' IF Column3='Y'
```

Can I do this in a single statement?

Comment: What if both `Column2` and `Column3` are `'Y'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably use a `CASE` statement.  My guess is that you want something like this

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET column5 = (CASE WHEN column2 = 'Y'
                       THEN 'TEACHER'
                       WHEN column3 = 'Y'
                       THEN 'STUDENT'
                       ELSE null
                   END)
 WHERE column2 = 'Y'
    OR column3 = 'Y'
```

I'm guessing that you don't want to update rows where neither condition is met.  If you want to update every row, you'll want to remove the `WHERE` clause and you may want to adjust what the default value is (the `ELSE` in the `CASE`) for rows where neither condition is met.

Comment: @Parallelis - True, in this case it's not necessary.  I included it in case the goal was to update every row in the table to show where the default value would go.